# Best traversal to create a mirror image of binary tree?

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I got an interview question. 
Which of the following is best to create Mirror image of a binary tree?
1.Inorder
2. Postorder
3. Preorder
4. Level order.

Can anyone explain which one will be used and why ?

Comment: Preorder with negated comparator logic should do it. (admittedly, thats off the cuff, but it seems to make sense). That assumes the tree is not self-balancing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `preorder` is best way to create mirror image :-

```
node* preorder(node* p) {

  if(p==null) {
       return(null);
  }  

  node* n = create(p->data);
  n->left = preorder(n->right);
  n->right = preorder(n->left);

  return(n);

}
```

Comment: Preorder traverse provides insertions sequence of the binary tree, therefore it is proper way to replicate inverted one...